# How to test Material UI 'error' color (red) with Jest/React Testing Library

Tags: jestjs, material-ui, react-testing-library

I have

```
<AppBar position='relative' color='error' data-testid='appbar'>
   ...
</AppBar>
```

and want to test

```
test('Appbar background color must be red', () => {
    render(<App />)
    const element = screen.getByTestId('appbar')
    expect(element).toHaveStyle(???)

})
```

The `???` part is where I am not sure what to put

Answer (score 0):

use `toHaveClass` instead of `toHaveStyle` and add the apprpriate class in terms of material UI.

```
test('Appbar background color must be red', () => {
    render(<App />);

    const element = screen.getByTestId('appbar')
    expect(element).toHaveClass("MuiAppBar-colorError");
});
```

Live Preview [live preview demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/elegant-sanderson-xk3oeu?file=/src/App.js)